# Inserting data into multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, application-design

For my system, students are required to create a user account by completing a registration form (personal, contact and course details; also username and password).

I need to collect registration data through a single form and insert the collected data into two related tables on my database (all student details in `student` table and login details in `users` table).

How best can I code this in php?

[image: Entity–relationship model]

Answer (score 5):

- Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) libraries for PHP, do not use mysql, as it is deprecated
- Use prepared statements: they are cleaner, less prone to SQL injection and, in some cases, faster to execute
- Use exceptions to capture errors throughout your code -query fails, query gets killed, database crashes, unable to connect, ...
- If you feel intimidated by SQL, an ORM can help you build your queries, but they are not without issues
- Students' id should have a foreign key referencing user_id, assuming you want a 1:1 relationship. To use foreign keys on MySQL you will want to use InnoDB stored engine.
- You cannot insert to two tables with a single statement, so you should use transactions. Start a transaction before inserting to the first table, then insert to the second one, then `COMMIT` the changes. That way, either the two inserts succeed or both fail. Transactions also require InnoDB.
- `student_id`/`user_id` are probably going to be unique arbitrary keys. You can use the `auto_increment` property for that column and do:

  ```
  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO student (last_name, fist_name, ...) VALUES ('Crespo', 'Jaime', ...);
  INSERT INTO users VALUES (last_insert_id(), 'jynus', 'hashedpassword', 'student');
  COMMIT;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not familiar with PDO, this means i have to start from scratch...
I have a foreign key “user-id” in the student table and also using the InnoDB engine; the student_id(PK) and user_id(PK) are both set to auto-increment, but as a foreign key the user_id in the student table is not set to auto_increment.

The PDO seems quite intimidating given i have very limited time to complete this.

I am new to programming my approach, can i use mysqli?
What are my options?

Comment: The php manual has long examples you can look at: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: how can i use this with the ON DELETE CASCADE?  i think the foreign keys should be in the child table.. am I right? @jynus